# Windows phone 8.1 Universal app - Show the Button all the time

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In Windows phone 8.1 universal app, Appbar currently support only icons, not the buttons. If i use the button, Button is hidden below the keyboard.

I need help to achieve either one of the below

1. I want to show the Button below the Keyboard, Any ways to achieve it?
2. Or, Move the Button above the Keyboard when keyboard appears.  When Keyboard is not shown, Button should be at the Bottom of the page. Is there any way to do this?

It helps User to see the Button clearly all the time.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an `ApplicationBarIconButton`?

Comment: ApplicationBarIconButton allow us to show only icons.  I try to add Button on BottomAppBar and I can't able to add button on BottomAppBar

Answer (score 0):

React on an OnInputPaneShowing event. The size of the input control is passed into this function and you can update the position of the button according this size.

See [MSDN respond to the keyboard presence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185611.aspx) and [MSDN occluded rect property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.occludedrect) for more info on how to do this.